# Generate a Tree result with Node.JS and MySQL using Promise

Tags: mysql, node.js, tree, promise

I'm trying to generate an array with a structured MySQL result

The BD structure with n-child is:

`-id
-title
-parent_id`

My recursive function with promise:

```js
let recursiveFindCat = (id) =>{
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        getChild(id);
        function getChild(id_c) {
            connections.getConnection(function(err, c){
                c.query("SELECT * FROM widgets WHERE parent_id='"+id_c+"'", function(error, results, fields) {
                    let array_tmp = Array();
                    if(results.length>0) {
                        results.forEach(function (item) {
                            array_tmp.push({
                                'id': item.id,
                                'title': item.title,
                                'childs': getChild(item.id)
                            });
                        });
                        console.log(array_tmp);
                        return array_tmp;
                    }else{
                        return resolve(array_tmp);
                    }


                });
            });
        }
    }); };
```

I'm testing the function with this:

```js
recursiveFindCat(0).then(function(ret_array){
       console.log(ret_array);
    });
```

The GetChild inside the array returns undefined always, I think it's because the async operation, I tried to put a promise inside that, just calling the recursiveFindCat again, but it not work.

There is a way to solve this using Promise?

Comment: Can you try this code https://pastebin.com/ZV4Z5WKU

Comment: I already tried to call the recursiveFindCat inside the child, but it generate a promise without resolution.

Comment: Eccel did you try running the code? In your code your aren't resolving / rejecting the promise.

Comment: Yes, i tried the code, but the childs node returns a not solved promise: childs: Promise { <pending> }